# OpenCV - Apache Storm occurrence of 'UnsatisfiedLinkError'

Tags: java, opencv, apache-storm

I am using (Apache Storm1.0.0 + OpenCV3.2.0) to distribute processing videos.

I have already submitted the topology to the cluster, but the workers don't seem to work. So I checked the logs of node3(worker) which did the spout  `job(ReadStreamSpout.java: read file from local)`.

[logs of node3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABFn9.png)

I really don't know what should I describe more....

Please let me know the information I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
String libopencv_java ="/path-to/libopencv_java2413.so";
System.load(libopencv_java);
```